# Stack Exchange API - Obtaining the Tag Watchers Count

Tags: support, tags, api, tag-watching

I've reviewed the entire [Stack Exchange API v2.2](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and have not found how to obtain the tag Watchers Count; e.g.:

[image]

How to obtain the 'watchers' count using the Stack Exchange API?

Comment: It's not possible in the API (and it's not in SEDE, either).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274618/finding-number-of-followers-of-a-tag-in-the-data-dump