# How frequently do people actually follow tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, statistics, followers

I have noticed that, even with the most popular tags (such as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)), there are very few followers for tags. I have read about tags in the Help Center to try and find some more info about this, but I'm still wondering if there's some statistics available for:

- How frequently do people actually follow tags?
- What is the most followed tag across all of the sites?
- Is the feature 'worth it' - as in, is it something that should be more/less promoted? Do people actually click on the feed items when they get notified about a tag?

Comment: You don't need to follow any tags here, there are few enough questions you can read 'em all as they come in. On busier non-meta sites tag following is much more useful though.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274618/finding-number-of-followers-of-a-tag-in-the-data-dump

Comment: Now that Custom Question Lists is out on all sites, watched/favorite tags are a little less useful, except as a way to highlight items. Ignored tags are much more useful. Still, on most sites (e.g. all meta sites) I don't watch nor ignore any tags.

Comment: How would you link tags across sites? A term could have very different meanings in different context. And different sites certainly are different contexts.